# Voila displays blank page

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, voila

I am trying to render a web application with Voila but the page turns out completely blank.
Running voila doesn't display any errors.
Output otherwise displays fine on Jupyter Notebook

Below are the relevant parts of my code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output, IFrame, HTML

!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix
!jupyter serverextension enable voila --sys-prefix

button_press = widgets.Button(
                description='Compare Telemetry',
                tooltip='Compare',
                style={'description_width': 'initial'}
            )

output = widgets.Output()

button_press.on_click(click)
vbox_result = widgets.VBox([button_press, output])

text_0 = widgets.HTML(value="<h1>Welcome to F1 Telemetry Comparison</h1>")
text_1 = widgets.HTML(value="<h3> Enter season</h3>")
text_2 = widgets.HTML(value="<h3> Enter driver initials to compare</h3>")
text_3 = widgets.HTML(value="<h3> Enter Grand Prix to compare</h3>")

text = widgets.VBox([text_0, text_1, season, text_2, name1, name2, text_3, gp, vbox_result])

page = widgets.VBox([text_0, text_1, season, text_2, name1, name2, text_3, gp, vbox_result])
display(page)
```

If anyone thinks seeing my full code might help let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Those two lines beginning in exclamation points should not be in your code or in the notebook. You already imported ipywidgets a few lines up & so you wouldn't be enabling the extension. Besides, you want extensions ready before you open a notebook page you are developing in. Maybe I'm wrong but it doesn't seem like you started with Voila working for an example? Did Voila work on your machine already before you tried coding your version of a page? I ask this because it doesn't look like how I've used it, but maybe it does work for you. There's a few ways to access it & so maybe I'm off base.

Comment: Also, these relevant parts aren't probably enough to debug your code; although it may be moot because you say it works in the notebook and maybe you aren't triggering Voila to open correctly? .... Thinking back to triggering Voila. Do you have a Voila button in your tool bar. And if you place the first four lines of code you've shared (everything before `button_press.`) in a new notebook and trigger the Voila view, so you see anything? If I do that, I see Enabling and Validating info. And a green indicator for each that it is `OK`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Wayne. I was able to fix the issue! It seems the version of Voila I was using (0.3.6) was incompatible with the version of ipywidgets (version 8). I installed an older version of ipywidgets (7.7.2) and now everything is working as expected. Cheers!